# Proof theory and subsystems of second-order arithmetic: in particular the reverse mathematics of Godel's system $T$

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory, reverse-math

While doing some research on reverse mathematics, I came across the following document under the address, http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/avigad/Talks/survey1.pdf:

> Proof theory and Subsystems of Second-Order Arithmetic

in which I found the following theorem and alleged proof, attributed to Godel (under the subheading, "The Dialectica interpretation"):

> Theorem (Godel):  The provably total recursive functions of $PA$ are exactly the primitive recursive functionals of type $\mathbb N$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb N$.
>
> Proof:  Write down a functional (quantifier-free) theory $T$ [presumably Godel's system $T$--my comment] whose terms denote the primitive recursive functionals of finite type.  From a proof of
>
> $\forall$ $x$$\exists$$y$$\varphi$($x$,$y$)
>
> in $PA$, one can extract a term $f$ and a proof of
>
> $\varphi$($x$, $f$($x$))
>
> in $T$.

With this in mind, I ask the following question:

> In which of the Big Five or their variants is Godel's System $T$ definable or equivalent to?

(Subsidiary questions:  Is the statement of the theorem correct?  Is it correctly attributable to Godel?  Is the proof as stated correct?)

Comment: Note that there's a crucial terminology distinction here (which I botched in a comment thread on the OP's prior question): primitive recursive function vs. primitive recursive function**al**.

Comment: Incidentally, [this cstheory.stackexchange answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37013/relative-consistency-of-pa-and-some-type-theories) looks relevant with regards to formulating the question more precisely - specifically, the difference between proving *consistency* and *normalization*. (There system F is talked about rather than system T, but at a glance I think the same issue holds.)

Comment: It is interesting to note that in Girard's  book _PROOFS AND TYPES_, Chapter 14 ("Strong normalization for $F$") one finds the following comment on pg. 113:  "...Existence is much more delicate; in fact, we shall see in Chapter 15 that the normalization theorem for $F$ implies the consistency of _second order arithmetic_ $PA_2$.  The classic result of logic, if anything deserves that name, is Godel's second incompleteness theorem, which says (assuming that it is not contradictory) that the consistency of $PA_2$ cannot be proved _within_ $PA_2$.  Consequently, since consistency _can_  be

Comment: (cont.) deduced from normalization within $PA_2$, the normalization theorem  _cannot_ be proved within $PA_2$.  That gives us an essential piece of information for the proof:  we must look for a strategy which goes outside $PA_2$."  Since the corollary, "All terms of $F$ are strongly normalisable" seems to be proven in a finite number of steps, strong normalisability is proven by finite means yet by means not provable in$PA_2$.  Would these means be 'ideal' in Hilbert's sense?

Comment: Note that what Girard means by "second-order arithmetic" is not the same as second-order Peano arithmetic - Girard's second-order arithmetic is a first-order theory. (In fact I think it's just Z$_2$.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  How is $Z_2$ related to $PA$, just for the record (am I to infer that $Z_2$ is a bi-sorted first-order theory)?

Comment: Z$_2$ is cosmically stronger than PA. Z$_2$ is the union of the theories $\Pi^1_n$-CA$_0$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$; even $\Pi^1_1$-CA$_0$ is galactically stronger than ATR$_0$, which is light-years more powerful than ACA$_0$ which is conservative over PA. While there's certainly an analogy between the two, Z$_2$ is a fundamentally different thing. (Meanwhile, your parenthetical is correct.)

Comment: While in the proposition in the middle of pg. 122 Girard states that, "The functions representable in $F$ are provably total in _second-order_ Peano arithmetic $PA_2$", at the bottom of pg. 122 he also states, "...But $PA_2$ is precisely the system of arithmetic with induction, comprehension, and second order quantification, which is $Z_2$.  Given also that the Wikipedia entry, "Second-order Arithmetic", under the subheading, "Definable functions", states that "The first-order functions that are provably total in second-order arithmetic are precisely the same as those representable in system

Comment: (cont.) $F$ (Girard and Taylor, 1987, pp. 122-123)", It would seem you are corrrect in inferring that $PA_2$ is $Z_2$(since Girard also states on Pg. 113, that "...we seek to use 'all possible' axioms of comprehension..." ).  But along with using all possible axioms of comprehension, one must therefore infer that one is using the full second-order induction scheme as well , so that $PA_2$ and $Z_2$ are equiconsistent (this from Carl Mummert's answer to David Roberts' mathoverflow question "$Z_2$ versus second-order $PA$ [question 97077]).  But still and all, Girard's statement, "we must look

Comment: (cont.) for a strategy [as regards proving normalization for $F$] which _goes outside_ $PA_2$", holds.